# Stretching the text (in particular in math mode) to fit the page size in a rough transfer (using "\\")

Tags: hyphenation

Sometimes the problem arises when the formula for the standard LaTeX facilities is torn wrong.
For example, he writes `x \in` on one line and `[a;b]` on the next.

So I have to do it `\\` to make transfers. However, after such transfers the first line is compressed.
For example (first 2 lines. I didn't want there to be a gap between "(b-" and "a) \epsilon").

[image]

[image]

The essence of the question is how to make LaTeX try to stretch the text on the line even in case of hyphenation (both when working with text and in math mode)?

Code from example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    $\left| \int\limits_a^b \phi \sin(\lambda x) dx \right| \leq
    \int\limits_a^b |\phi(x)-\phi_\epsilon(x)| dx +
    \left| \int\limits_a^b \phi_\epsilon(x) \sin(\lambda x) dx \right| < \\
    (b - a) \epsilon + \epsilon = (b - a + 1) \epsilon$.

    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us a short compilable code resulting in your image to play with ...

Comment: added sample code

Comment: When such an expression is submitted in an article to a journal, it would be edited as a display, not set in-line in the text.  The `align*` environment from `amsmath` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you are looking for `\linebreak` rather than `\\`  so the line is still justified, alsthough such a math expression would normally be set using a math alignment such as `\begin{align*}` not a justified inline math expression as here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    $\left| \int\limits_a^b \phi \sin(\lambda x) dx \right| \leq
    \int\limits_a^b |\phi(x)-\phi_\epsilon(x)| dx +
    \left| \int\limits_a^b \phi_\epsilon(x) \sin(\lambda x) dx \right| < \linebreak
    (b - a) \epsilon + \epsilon = (b - a + 1) \epsilon$.

    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```